# how to run a nextjs app locally with a vpn

Tags: authentication, next.js, vpn, clerk

So ClerkJS (the library I am using for authentication in my NextJS app) is banned in Pakistan where I live. I want to use Clerk since I am following a tutorial that not only uses Clerk in the app itself but also uses other libraries like uploadthing which also use ClerkJS for authentication. The problem is if I use a vpn to bypass the restrictions and access the ClerkJS website and UploadThing website then the nextJS app I am running gives the error of "The requested URL was not found".

So I need to use a vpn during my development however then my NextJS app will not work. I am using the free tier of VeePN on Firefox.

I have tried googling for a solution but nothing came up.